# How could one duplicate the same environment configuration as a database server?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm interested in making my local postgres server config match the production one. Given a psql connection to it, would it be possible to run some queries and extract the relevant performance options? Alternatively, if this is not possible, does anyone know the configuration options for heroku's paid postgres plans?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? The performance options are supposedly matching the PG installation to the available hardware and the typical server usage scenario. I do not think you have the same hardware (at least, how can you be sure?) and the typical server usage scenario will be different almost by default. What do you expect to learn from having the same performance configuration settings under different circumstances?

Comment: What do you exactly need? A solution for matching heroku's pg performance or a configuration clone that allows you to have a similar workflow locally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will show you all settings for the server.

> `SELECT current_setting(name), *
>   FROM pg_catalog.pg_settings`

Then you can look at the postgresql.conf to see what has been set manually.

If you don't have any access to the postgresql.conf, use the above query on some other server and see what's different :)

Comment: Do you know if it would be possible to read the postgresql.conf using the psql command line?

Comment: @Tempus: if it's in the data directory, `select * from pg_read_file('postgresql.conf');` as a db superuser.

Comment: @Kirk Roybal: `current_setting(name)` is no more than a pretty rendering of `setting` and `unit` columns, so rather superfluous. @Daniel Verite: On Heroku a regular user has no `SUPERUSER` privileges.

Comment: The query above shows has a "configuration_file" column, which would show where the setting originated.  @Patrick: There could be a difference between what was set in a configuration file, and what was set in the current transaction for making a connection.  setting and current_setting(name) are therefore only interesting if they're different for some reason.

Comment: @DanielVérité Nice succinct way to do what klin does in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as long as you have permission to read the remote config file (change the delimiter at a pinch).

```
create table conf(
  line text
);

do $$ 
begin
  execute 
    format(
      'copy conf from ''%s'' delimiter ''|''', 
      current_setting('config_file'));
end $$;

select * from conf;
```

Two maybe helpful tips.

```
-- skip empty and commented lines:

select line from conf
where line != '' and ltrim(line, e' \t') not like '#%';

-- copy conf to file:

copy (select replace(line, e'\t', '    ') from conf) to 'c:/data/postgres.conf';
```

Comment: Must be `SUPERUSER` to read config_file and that is not the case on Heroku for remote users.

Comment: Here's how to do that without a temp table and quoting issues:

WITH conf AS (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(pg_read_file(current_setting('config_file')), E'\n')) line)
SELECT array_to_string(array(
SELECT line
FROM conf
WHERE not line ~ '^[[:space:]]*#' AND length(line) > 0), E'\n')